# Are there breeds of cats that are more social than others?

Tags: cats

I have met some cats that are highly social:

- they look you in the eye when they see you and are visibly enthousiastic, and they meow.
- they give you head bumps.
- when they see you outside they run enthousiastically towards you and are clearly happy with your company.

Then there are cats that are somewhat a-social. I don't mean that they are aggressive or mean, but that they just are more indifferent towards human company and will want to be alone more often.

**Are there specific breeds of cats that are significantly and visibly more social than others?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes and no.

All cats that are in a recognized breed, are among others, selected for sociability. Also known as, do they get along well, or very well, with their humans. Other cats (strays) have a more random selection. If the cat is feral that selection is often how well they can hunt or scavenge.

But the big thing is how well a cat knows you! My cats are very friendly with me. But not so with strangers.

*Social behaviour in cats is linked to longer kitten like behaviour. Also known as: they keep traits of kittens their life long, so they make better pets.

### How to get a social cat

1) Easy: find someone who raises kittens well, might be breeder, might be rescue centre. Then go and play with these bundles of joy. One will stand out for you. Or better yet, one will pick you as it's butler. (pro for social: not skiddish, playful, curious and no aggression.

2) Harder: go to your local rescue and find the cat that seems to like you the most.

Comment: I highly recommend a shelter or a rescue organization to find your companion. With literally billions of companion animals euthanized every year, saving a life is a heroic deed. There are breed-specific rescues as well.

Comment: @M.Mat I've included breeders as well, not every country has a rescue system in place.

Comment: I have never seen or heard of a country that doesn’t have some “rescue” of animals in trouble. Such efforts may not be institutional or organizational but animal lovers and protectors exist everywhere. For example there is a small group in War-ravaged Syria that are rescuing the strays and abandoned pets while bombs are going off. Breeders in my opinion, shouldn’t be an option.

Answer (score 4):

Nature or Nurture is still fertile ground for philosophical and scientific exploration.The “temperament” question that each 
personality paradigm provides, has always been a bugaboo.

I’m of the mind, based on my personal experience and observations, that as a matter of course, both arenas figure in the “beingness” of all creatures.

Internet research with the observations of others, professional and anecdotal alike, can provide rudimentary answers about sociability of particular breeds. Ultimately, it comes down to how kittens are reared and how interactive we humans are in the socialization these creatures.

I have had companion cats for several decades. Rescues, orphans, strays, from age two days, to senior cats adopted near the end of their lives. In all of my many associations with felines, one kind of cat sticks out as “most sociable:” The Male Orange Tabby.

My soulmate, companion cat was rescued by me at 12 weeks old. We spent 20.3 years together. His passing 12 years ago, stays with me. I honestly think about this cat everyday.

Orange Tabbies are warm, attentive, independent, adventurous empathy that seem to just bring light to the planet.

Visit your local shelter and find an Orangeman of your own.